# How to run all methods with a given annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

This is what I want to happen:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        run @mod(); // run all methods annotated with @mod annotation
    }
}
```

The **annotation** declaration:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface mod {
   String name() default "";
}
```

The **methods** to be called:

```
public class Good {
    @mod (name = "me1")
    public void calledcs(){
        System.out.println("called");
    }

    @mod (name = "me2")
    public void calledcs2(){
        System.out.println("called");
    }
}
```

or is there another way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: That's not possible. What exactly do you want to achieve? What do you want to happen in your example?

Comment: to be able to call function without going into other classes.

Comment: As Arian said, you're not really describing what you want to happen - nor what your problem is.

Comment: I'd appreciate more clarity on this question's intention. Valid suggestions below, but the direction is questionable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it using classpath scanning: Basically you go over every method of every class in the classpath and get all annotated with your given annotation. After that, you invoke the found methods.

Below is a `runAllAnnotatedWith()` method that would do it. It uses **[Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)** to do the dirty work of classpath scanning. *For simplicity, it executes all found methods as if they were `static` and required no parameters.*

```
public static void runAllAnnotatedWith(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation)
                                                               throws Exception {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                  .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forJavaClassPath())
                                  .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner()));
    Set<Method> methods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(annotation);

    for (Method m : methods) {
        // for simplicity, invokes methods as static without parameters
        m.invoke(null); 
    }
}
```

You can run it using:

```
runAllAnnotatedWith(mod.class);
```

**Note:** It is possible to do it without using [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections), but the code will get dirtier and dirtier.

Here's the full code (paste it all into a RunClass.java file):

```
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Set;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.MethodAnnotationsScanner;
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;

public class RunClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        runAllAnnotatedWith(mod.class);
    }

    public static void runAllAnnotatedWith(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) throws Exception {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forJavaClassPath()).setScanners(
                        new MethodAnnotationsScanner()));
        Set<Method> methods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(annotation);

        for (Method m : methods) {
            m.invoke(null); // for simplicity, invoking static methods without parameters
        }
    }
    
    @mod(name = "me1")
    public static void calledcs() {
        System.out.println("called");
    }

    @mod(name = "me2")
    public static void calledcs2() {
        System.out.println("called2");
    }
}

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface mod {
    String name() default "";
}
```

To run it, you have to add the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) JAR to your project. **You can download it [here](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/reflections/reflections/0.9.12/reflections-0.9.12.jar)**.

If you use Maven, you can add it using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.9-RC1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use reflection technique.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface mod {
   public String name() default "";
}

public class Fundamental {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Get all methods in order.
      // runClass is the class you declare all methods with annotations.
      Method[] methods = runClass.getMethods();
      for(Method mt : methods) {
        if (mt.isAnnotationPresent(mod.class)) {
            // Invoke method with appropriate arguments
            Object obj = mt.invoke(runClass, null);
        }
      } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using an open source library I have published recently, called Reflect:

```
List<Method> methods = Reflect.on(someClass).methods().annotatedWith(mod.class);
for (Method m : methods) {
  m.invoke(null);
}
```

Maven Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.pacesys</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflect</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

More Recipes found at: https://github.com/gondor/reflect

Comment: Please add a disclaimer that you are promoting your own project.