# How to use reflection to identify annotated methods?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

We are trying to use reflection to extract the exact mapped values to our methods. The code structure in the target module consists of multiple classes as follows -

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/questions")
public class XYZController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/ask")
  public boolean myMethod1() {..}

  @RequestMapping(value = "/{questionNo.}/{questionTitle}")
  public MyReturnObject myMethod2(){..}

}
```

What we are trying to grep here is the list of endpoints like `/questions/ask` and `/questions/{questionNo.}/{questionTitle}` for which the code we tried to execute filters all such classes based on the `@Controller` annotation and at the same time we are able to get the list of all the endpoints separately. The code we have tried so far is  -

```
public class ReflectApi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider scanner = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
        final List<String> filteredClasses = new ArrayList<>();
        scanner.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(Controller.class));
        Set<BeanDefinition> filteredPackage = scanner.findCandidateComponents("com.package.test");

        // gives me a list of all the filtered classes
        filteredPackage.stream().forEach(beanDefinition -> filteredClasses.add(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName()));

        // call to get the annotation details
        filteredClasses.stream().forEach(filteredClass -> getEndPoints(filteredClass));
    }

    public static void getEndPoints(String controllerClassName) {
        try {
            Class clazz = Class.forName(controllerClassName);
            Annotation classAnnotation = clazz.getDeclaredAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
            if (classAnnotation != null) {
                RequestMapping mappedValue = (RequestMapping) clazz.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
                System.out.println("Controller Mapped -> " + mappedValue.value()[0]); //This gives me the value for class like "/questions"
                runAllAnnotatedWith(RequestMapping.class);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // followed from a SO reference
    public static void runAllAnnotatedWith(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder().setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forJavaClassPath())
                .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner()));
        Set<Method> methods = reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(annotation);

        methods.stream().forEach(m -> {
            if (m != null) {
                RequestMapping mappedValue = m.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class); //this is listing out all the @RequestMapping annotations like "/questions" , "/ask" etc.
                    System.out.println(mappedValue.value()[0]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**But the missing part is the concatenation of the class to method RequestMapping value here.**

How do we loop inside a class to search annotations only from its methods?

Or is there any simpler way of doing this from what we are using?

References used - [Scanning Java annotations at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259140/scanning-java-annotations-at-runtime) && [How to run all methods with a given annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996033/how-to-run-all-methods-with-a-given-annotation)

Comment: The one thing I dont get: how/where do you create **instances** of your controller objects? Your methods arent static, so on "which" objects do you invoke them?

Comment: How does the method being static/non-static relate to reflection ? @GhostCat

Comment: As said: knowing *classes* and *methods* is one thing. But if you want to use **reflection** to invoke methods, too ... then you need to know the **object** to invoke on, too. Just the javadoc for Method.invoke()!

Comment: @GhostCat In my case I am not bothered of calling the `invoke()` anyway, the motive is not to use any functionality but to get the mappings as of now.

Comment: Ok, one thing: as you didnt comment on my answer - does it help you in any way; or is it missing something you need?

Comment: @GhostCat - the reason I didn't comment yet is, coz its more of ideal concepts, which I am currently trying to implement right now. Once completed would confirm :)

Comment: Fine; let me know if there is anything i can help with/or that would improve the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aren't endpoints **methods** in the end?

So, I think what you need to implement is:

1. => Retrieve all **[declared methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods())** of each and any class that has `@RequestMapping` and `@Controller` annotations.
2. => Iterate the annotations on each of those **[Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html)** objects to check if they contain `@RequestMapping`

**OR**

2. => Iterate through all the `Method`s for each class in *Step 1* and find the annotated one's using `method.getDeclaredAnnotation(RequestMapping.class)` and skip *Step 3*
3. => Remember that combination of **class** and **method** for your mapping
4. => Do some error handling, in case you don't find *any* annotated method in there.