# Invoke annotated method with necessary params

Tags: java, annotations

I have methods annotated as follows:

```
    @Action(actionType=<..>)
    public void doSomeAction() {
      ...
    }
```

Now, I would like to invoke one of such annotated methods with given `actionType` from another flow in another class.

In order to do this, I found the approaches as mentioned in the following SO posts:

1. [How to run all methods with a given annotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996033/how-to-run-all-methods-with-a-given-annotation)
2. [Java seek a method with specific annotation and its annotation element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593597/java-seek-a-method-with-specific-annotation-and-its-annotation-element)

But in some cases, such methods may accept arguments as follows:

```
 @Action(actionType='SEND_NOTIFICATION')
 public void sendReport(String email) {
  ...
 }
```

In this regard, I am not able to understand, how to check if the annotated method has any params and invoke such methods with required params.

Comment: Once you have a `Method` object you can check what parameters it takes and provide them when you invoke it.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks for your response. If possible, would you mind sharing, small code snippet for the same?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't just let Spring do this with `@EventListener`, or use Spring Integration if you need more granular setup? It's a solved problem.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-Thanks. No there is no reason as such. Actually, I don't have much idea working with either EventListener or spring integration.

Comment: `Method m = ...; Class[] paramTypes = m.getParameterTypes(); m.invoke(theObject,  params...);` but what are you actually trying to do, what's your environment?

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks. Actually, I am working on a spring boot application, wherein a given flow, I would like to invoke such function annotated with a specific value.

Comment: Use @EventListener then, and the individual event types can contain the parameters (so all the methods just take an event)